# Multiple pages in one component Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to create multiple pages in one component in Angular. I just want to put data in one page that should be saved in database. When I press submit button data should save and next page within same component should render take it data submit and new page  should come so on and so forth up to 20 to 25 pages. How Could It be possible in Angular 10?

Comment: Plese take a tour to understand how to do it with angular . https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular Material in your project, you can achieve this by using `mat-stepper` like this:

[image]

First, you need to add `Angular Material` to your project:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

and then you need to import your desired module in the module that your component has been declared into. in this case, add mat-stepper module:

```
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
```

**Keep that in mind to add `MatStepperModule` into `imports` array of your module as well.**

and then you can use it in your component

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Stepper with editable steps
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-editable-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-editable-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-editable-example.css']
})
export class StepperEditableExample implements OnInit {
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  isEditable = false;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="isEditable = !isEditable">
  {{!isEditable ? 'Enable edit mode' : 'Disable edit mode'}}
</button>

<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" [editable]="isEditable">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="firstCtrl" placeholder="Last name, First name" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" [editable]="isEditable">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY"
               required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    <p>You are now done.</p>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular material tab option .You can add next button where we increase the selectedIndex to go to the next tab and save the work by calling a function on clicking the button.